# Can Recaptcha be used in a profile HTML form snippet on a non-Civi web page?

Tags: profile, recaptcha

When setting up a profile for people to subscribe to a newsletter, in the 'Settings' area next to the Recaptcha box there's a blue help bubble which says *'Do not enable this feature if you are using this profile as an HTML Form Snippet embedded in a non-CiviCRM web page. reCAPTCHA requires dynamic page generation. Submitting a stand-alone form with reCAPTCHA included will always result in a reCAPTCHA validation error.'* Is this really the case?  I noticed some answers on here telling people to add Recaptcha to profiles to avoid spam.

Comment: guessing this is likely to be a big NO. did you get anywhere further with this?

Comment: Well...I went ahead with the profile & no recaptcha - and we got spammed badly.  So I switched to a webform.  Hey ho.

Comment: how did a webform help get it on to a remote site? i didn't think that was possible. or you mean you had it on same site?

Comment: The external website had some words and a link to the webform, which I made look as close as possible to the website, & the webform included a Recaptcha.  This is a D7 site.

Comment: ok. yep that makes sense. am pretty sure we once did an embed from a d7 webform to an external site, so we just used ThemeKey to deliver a completely blank theme for the hosting site, so the embed did have any evidence of coming from another site.